# CSS Grid and min-content/auto

Tags: css, css-grid

So I'm trying to create the below image with CSS grid. min-content and auto doesn't seem to be playing nice. Here is a fiddle! https://jsfiddle.net/pw9L52h0/

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="label-1">label 1</div>
  <div class="label-2">label 2</div>
  <div class="label-3">label 3</div>
  <div class="label-4">label 4</div>
  <div class="label-5">label 5</div>
  <div class="label-6">label 6</div>
  <div class="label-7">label 7</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 60px min-content auto;
  grid-template-columns: 60px min-content auto;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.label-1 {
  grid-row-start: 0;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  grid-column-start: 0;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.label-2 {
  grid-row-start: 0;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  background-color: green;
}

.label-3 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 0;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.label-4 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.label-5 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  background-color: orange;
}

.label-6 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  background-color: pink;
}

.label-7 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

It ends up like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating this where you only need few line of code like below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 60px min-content auto;
  grid-template-columns: 60px min-content auto;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.label-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.label-2 {
  grid-column:span 2; /* this */
  background-color: green;
}

.label-3 {
  grid-row:span 2; /* and this */
  background-color: blue;
}

.label-4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.label-5 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.label-6 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.label-7 {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="label-1">label 1</div>
  <div class="label-2">label 2</div>
  <div class="label-3">label 3</div>
  <div class="label-4">label 4</div>
  <div class="label-5">label 5</div>
  <div class="label-6">label 6</div>
  <div class="label-7">label 7</div>
</div>
```

The main issue with your code is that you are counting from `0` where you need to start from `1`. 3 columns means 4 lines (1,2,3,4).

You can clearly see in the console that `grid-start-* = 0` is invalid and `grid-end-* = 1` will place the end of the element at the first line creating an implicit new column/row at the beginning thus you will end having 4 columns/rows:

[image]

Here is your code fixed with the correct numbers:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 60px min-content auto;
  grid-template-columns: 60px min-content auto;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.label-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  background-color: red;
}

.label-2 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  background-color: green;
}

.label-3 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  background-color: blue;
}

.label-4 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.label-5 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  background-color: orange;
}

.label-6 {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  background-color: pink;
}

.label-7 {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="label-1">label 1</div>
  <div class="label-2">label 2</div>
  <div class="label-3">label 3</div>
  <div class="label-4">label 4</div>
  <div class="label-5">label 5</div>
  <div class="label-6">label 6</div>
  <div class="label-7">label 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, so CSS Grids automatically fixes that. I am curious though, when I set specifically the row-start, column start etc. Am I not doing exactly what is expected? Or is there something with CSS Grids that I am unaware of?

Comment: @K-ToxicityinSOisgrowing. you are making the grid algorithm a bit tricky and your grid is creating an extra row and an extra column due to all the start/end you are using. I will try to update to explain why this is happening but the auto placement is enough for your and only 2 items need to span either 2 columns or 2 rows

Comment: So starting from zero was the culrpit! Thanks a million dude!

Comment: @K-ToxicityinSOisgrowing. I would say ending in 1 is the culprit ;) starting from 0 is invalid and will have no effect.

Comment: Haha I guess you could say that.